# MySQL: WHERE condition for LEFT JOIN if all items in GROUPS do not match

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, publications and issues in it. I want to show list of publications and count of issues in each. This is simple:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.title
     , COUNT(i.id) AS countOfIssues 
  FROM publications p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN issues i 
    ON p.id = i.publicationId 
 GROUP 
    BY p.id;
```

But, issues can have "deleted" column set to 1 and I want to count only undeleted issues. Also, if there is no issue, I want to show publication row, so:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.title
     , COUNT(i.id) AS countOfIssues 
  FROM publications p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN issues i 
    ON p.id = i.publicationId 
 WHERE i.deleted = 0 
    OR i.deleted IS NULL 
 GROUP 
    BY p.id;
```

But this fails in situation, when all issues in publications have deleted=1. In that case, this publication row is missing.

How to improve WHERE condition?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it is so simple, the condition has to be inside JOIN:

`SELECT p.id, p.title, COUNT(i.id) AS countOfIssues FROM publications p LEFT JOIN issues i ON p.id=i.publicationId AND i.deleted=0 GROUP BY p.id;`

Answer (score 0):

WHERE is not what you searching for in this situation.

Option1 As Michal Politzer but with NOT NULL condition:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, COUNT(i.id) AS countOfIssues
FROM publications p 
LEFT JOIN issues i ON p.id = i.publicationId and (i.deleted = 0 OR i.deleted IS NULL)
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Option2 with switch case:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, 
COUNT(case when i.id = 0 OR i.deleted IS NULL THEN i.id ELSE NULL END) AS countOfIssues 
FROM publications p 
LEFT JOIN issues i ON p.id = i.publicationId
GROUP BY p.id;
```